# Compact formula for 8 bit numbers which start with 1

Tags: binary, hex, formula, bit

I am a newbie and a little bit lost and cannot find a solution.
I Need to find a formula in Hex which says all 8 bit numbers that start with 1.
I Need this to check if it is the first Byte of my laser. (Start Byte ist marked with a 1).

First I just wrote: if.. == 0x80
But now I realized that this is only 10000000.
How can I find a formula without write ALL numbers down that start with 1?

Thanks for any tipps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bitwise AND operator` like this:

```
if(myByte & 0x80) {
    // leftmost bit of myByte is set
}
```